# Cant copy on a struct with a string so how do I fix this?

Tags: rust

Consider the following struct:

```
pub struct Character {
    pub name: String
}

pub fn build_character(name: String) -> Character {
    Character {
        name,
    }
}
```

nothing complicated yet, so now that we have a character built by passing a string name to the `build_character`, we pass this struct to a new function:

```
pub fn create_game(character: Character) -> Game {
    Game  {
        active: true,
        game_character: character,
    }
}
```

The game stuff is defined below:

```
pub struct Game {
    active: bool,
    game_character: Character,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn is_active(&self) -> bool {
        return self.active;
    }

    pub fn set_acive(&mut self, active: bool) {
        self.active = active;
    }

    pub fn get_character(&self) -> Character {
        return self.game_character;
    }

    pub fn update_character(&mut self, character: Character) {
        self.game_character = character;
    }
}
```

This is where we have issues.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.game_character` which is behind a shared reference
  --> game/src/game/set_up_game.rs:19:16
   |
19 |         return self.game_character;
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.game_character` has type `character::character::charactersheet::Character`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

in function:

```
    pub fn get_character(&self) -> Character {
        return self.game_character;
    }
```

This makes sense. But as we all know we cannot add the copy trait to the character struct because strings cannot be copied, they are pointers to memory. I tried clone, but that doesn't work either, I get the same error.

(Clone annd Copy are for the Character struct according to the error).

The idea here is that the game object is passed around allowing me to update the character, think inventory, spells, health, so on and so forth.

I would fetch the game object fetch the character, update the character and then set the character back on the game object.

So my question is how do we fix this issue?

Comment: The `Clone` trait can be easily derived by adding `#[derive(Clone)]` to the struct. Here it would make more sense to just return `&Character` instead of `Character` (then you can still clone it afterwards, but don't have to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibility 1: Implement/derive `Clone` for `Character` and return a clone:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Character {
    pub name: String
}

pub struct Game {
    active: bool,
    game_character: Character,
}

impl Game {
    // possibility 1
    pub fn get_character(&self) -> Character {
        return self.game_character.clone();
    }
}
```

Possibility 2: Return a reference.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Character {
    pub name: String
}

pub struct Game {
    active: bool,
    game_character: Character,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn get_character(&self) -> &Character {
        return &self.game_character;
    }
}
```

Possibility 2 (returning reference) has the advantage that it is cheap, and the caller can decide themselves if they actually need a copy, in which case the caller just manually `clone`s the thing.